# How do I load a customized javascript file for each user based on the PHP login?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm running a web-based experiment where students log into a website and take practice tests for a class.  Currently the students start on a login page with this code:

```
include_once("core/config.php");
include_once("core/db.class.php");
include_once("core/log.class.php");
session_start();

$debug = false;

$loginSuccess = "";
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
{       
    $db = new DB($DbCatalog,$DbHost, $DbUser, $DbPass);
    $log = new log($db);

    foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $key)
    {
        $cleanParam[$key] = addslashes($_POST[$key]);
    }

    $result = $db->query("select count(*) as valid from Login where Email='" . $cleanParam["uname"] . "' and Pass='" . $cleanParam["pass"] . "'", $debug);
    $line = $db->fetchNextObject($result);
    if ($line->valid == 1)
    {
        $log_type = 'login-success';
        $log_data = 'User '.$cleanParam["uname"].' successfully logged in';
        $log->write($log_type, $log_data);

        $_SESSION["logged_in"] = $cleanParam["uname"];
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $log_type = 'login-error';
        $log_data = 'User '.$cleanParam["uname"].' logged in failed with password '.$cleanParam["pass"];
        $log->write($log_type, $log_data);

        $loginSuccess = '<span class="errorMsg">Email/Password combination not found.</span>';
    }
}
else
{
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

After logging in, students go to the index page with this code:

```
include_once("core/config.php");
include_once("core/db.class.php");

session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]))
{
    header("Location: login.php");  
}

$hdnUser = "";
$hdnUser = $_SESSION["logged_in"];  

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Scientific Name Quiz</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">

<script language="javascript" src="quiz_database.js">
```

That final bit of code attaches the database of questions and answers for the experiment (quiz_database.js).  But I'm now at the point in my experiment where I need to customize the database for each user who logs in.

**Question: How do I modify the above code so that I can attach a specific, customized database for each user, based on the username used at login?**

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `customized database`? Will each user, after logging in, connect to different database, or should the `quiz_database.js` file be different for each user (or do different things depending upon the user)

Comment: There will be a different quiz_database.js file for each user.  So I'll set up something like `quiz_database_Fred.js` and `quiz_database_Lucy.js` and so forth (probably with a more logical naming system).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in multiple ways:

- as you've written in comment - have different scripts for different users. As such, you'd do `<script language="javascript" src="/<?php echo(generate_user_hash($cleanParam["uname"])); ?>/quiz_database.js">` - so each user will have different, non-guessable path name (pros: fast to implement; cons: hard to manage, will grow with more users).
- generate js file for each user: ([PHP - generating JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152055/php-generating-javascript) - generally you only are required to send proper header `header("Content-Type: text/javascript");` though given problem shows how such PHP generated JS file would look like). While this approach isn't sensible where there's multiple users visiting the site (as JS file needs to be generated for each user independantly) it will work here, as each JS file will be different. (pros: code should be clear to read and modify as you'll generally have blocks for each user; cons: handling JS with PHP while moving between languages - it's easier if you've got some kind of templating system, or are storing questions in DB)
- have one js file, that runs JSONP-like requests to the PHP handler - as such your `quiz_database.js` will be just proxy that will execute question functions received from the server (pros: you have separation of JS and PHP, and if you're not storing questions in the DB, you can put each of the questions (or each of user's questions) in separate file; cons: more work [but not that much] / need to secure the questions, so different users don't access not somebody elses questions). (JSONP-like, because you might want to handle different cases [for users accessing their own questions, and not their own questions] in JS)

Personally, I'd implement the approach number 3. I'd store each of questions as separate JS file and maintain in the DB which question the user has access to. I'd create a function (in jquery - please treat it as a general idea on how to treat received data; I don't know if you're even using jquery; as such this is just a stub)

```
function get_question()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/get_question/",
        success: function(response)
        {
            if (response.error)
               window.alert(response.error);
            else
               response.function();
        }
    });
}
```

which would be called to get the JS code of latest question (as they're logged in, it will load different JS file for each user. Then your PHP controller would only have to pull out the correct file and serve it as text.

Comment: Jeez, you forgot to parse JSON string (a response variable)

Comment: Did you mention `dataType:json`?

Comment: @bad_boy - I didn't mention `header('Content-Type: application/json');` which can be used as well. I'd say - whichever approach works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your goal, the snippet above should be slightly amended

Change the following part of the first snippet

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT Email AS username FROM Login WHERE Email='" . $cleanParam["uname"] . "' AND Pass='" . $cleanParam["pass"] . "' LIMIT 1", $debug);
if($line = $db->fetchNextObject($result){
    $log_type = 'login-success';
    $log_data = 'User '.$cleanParam["uname"].' successfully logged in';
    $log->write($log_type, $log_data);

    $_SESSION["logged_in"] = $cleanParam["uname"];
    $_SESSION["username"] = $line->username;
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    // ...
}
```

Change the following part of the second snippet

```
<script language="javascript" src="quiz_database_<?php echo $_SESSION["username"] ?>.js">
```

Of course, there are other ways to achieve the same, but I followed your logic :)